# Realizar binding ida y vuelta con 2 objetos y knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, knockoutjs

Quisiera saber si es posible realizar un binding entre dos objetos (`viewmodel`), el primero es creado como parte de la función y el  otro se crea a partir del `Get`, y la propiedad que quisiera sincronizar entre los dos `viewModels` es `visibleTabs`  con `ultimoNivel` con KnockoutJS.

Mi código actual es el siguiente:

```
var vm = function() {
var self = this;
this.visibleTabs = ko.observable(false);
this.select = function(e) {
    var idEquipo = treeview().dataItem(e.node).id;
    var equipo = Get("equipo/getbyid/" + idEquipo).responseText;
    self.equipo(ko.mapping.fromJS(JSON.parse(equipo)));
    self.visibleTabs(self.equipo().ultimoNivel());
}
this.visibleTabsChange = ko.computed(function () {
    if (self.equipo()) {
        self.equipo().ultimoNivel(self.visibleTabs());
    }

});}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución que encontré fue cambiar  la función `computed` de KnockouJS por un `subscribe` de `visibleTabsChange`, asimismo la siguiente linea `self.visibleTabs(self.equipo().ultimoNivel());` también fue movida al `subscribe` del la propiedad `equipo`  el código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
var vm = function() {
var self = this;
this.visibleTabs = ko.observable(false);
this.select = function(e) {
    var idEquipo = treeview().dataItem(e.node).id;
    var equipo = Get("equipo/getbyid/" + idEquipo).responseText;
    self.equipo(ko.mapping.fromJS(JSON.parse(equipo)));
    self.visibleTabs(self.equipo().ultimoNivel());
}
this.visibleTabs.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    if (self.equipo()) {
        self.equipo().ultimoNivel(newValue);
    }
});
this.equipo.subscribe(function () {
    self.visibleTabs(self.equipo().ultimoNivel());
});}
```